# Cyrillic symbols in class file

Tags: document-classes, cyrillic

Can't get cyrillic symbols from class file. A minimal example follows.

.cls

```
\ProvidesClass{class}

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont}

\RequirePackage{tempora}

\AtBeginDocument{}
\AtEndDocument{}

\def\thepage{1}
\newenvironment{proof}{%
  \subparagraph{Доведення}%
}{%
}

\def\subparagraph{\@startsection
  {subparagraph}{4}{0pt}{16pt}{-1em}{}}
```

.tex

```
\documentclass{class}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
proof goes here
\end{proof}
А тут працює!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Check the input encoding of the class file.

Comment: If your users decide to use another encoding, they will see strange stuff. That is why class files usually are encoding independant and use the low level constructs to write predefined text strings.

Comment: @Johannes_B `text/x-tex; charset=us-ascii`, i'm translating a book, where should i move such definitions? Create `.sty` for it?

Comment: @Johannes_B you can form you comments as an answer if you like

Comment: ASCII does not contain much more than the latin alphabet. You would need to encode the file in utf8 and make sure to load package `inputenc` before introducing non-ascii stuff. But i would rather not do that.

Comment: I 'dont like to answer if i don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

When LaTeX is reading the class file, the `inputenc` package has not yet been loaded, unless you do it in the class.

Thus a solution might be (sorry for changing the class name, it's for avoiding clobbering my files):

```
\ProvidesClass{yola}

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{tempora}

\AtBeginDocument{}
\AtEndDocument{}

\def\thepage{1}
\newenvironment{proof}{%
  \subparagraph{Доведення}%
}{%
}

\def\subparagraph{\@startsection
  {subparagraph}{4}{0pt}{16pt}{-1em}{}}
```

However, this forces users of your class to use UTF-8.

An encoding independent solution would be

```
\ProvidesClass{yola}

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont}

\RequirePackage{tempora}

\AtBeginDocument{}
\AtEndDocument{}

\def\thepage{1}
\newenvironment{proof}{%
  \subparagraph{\CYRD\cyro\cyrv\cyre\cyrd\cyre\cyrn\cyrn\cyrya}%
}{%
}

\def\subparagraph{\@startsection
  {subparagraph}{4}{0pt}{16pt}{-1em}{}}
```

[image]